# Why is Algeria called "Argélia" and Algiers called "Argel" in Portuguese?

Tags: etimologia

Note the swapping of R and L. Given that the name of the country is derived from the name of the city, and the English name matches the Arabic name "al-Jazā’er" more closely, when and why did the swap occur in the formation of the Portuguese name of these places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com este [autor](http://sualingua.com.br/2014/07/06/argelia-ou-algeria/) a origem desta diferença vem da interpretação que os primeiros falantes do Português fizeram ao ouvir palavras estrangeiras. Especialmente neste caso em que o alfabeto local era diferente do nosso.

> Essas variantes são extremamente comuns quando se trata de lugares descobertos ou
>   visitados há centenas de anos. Nossos antepassados interpretaram à sua
>   moda os nomes estranhos que ouviram ― friso: apenas **ouviram**, porque a
>   escrita, geralmente em alfabetos exóticos, não entrava aqui em
>   cogitação ― e assim fixaram-se certos nomes que destoam dos que são
>   utilizados por outros países.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, one of our users, [João de Barros](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-377/joao-de-barros), might know the answer. Being a famous historian, he already wrote "Argel" for the city Algiers in 1552. Here is the original¹

[image: argel]

(Decadas da Aſia (1552). Liuro ſexto, Fo. 58)

<sub>¹ courtesy of John Carter Brown Library via archive.org</sub>

Whether this was him following or starting a trend, or whether it was just one of his L ↔ R [typos](http://laures.cc.sophia.ac.jp/laures/pageview/id=JL-1552-KB2-117-48/page=iiiR/zoom/)

[image: erros]
[image: ingraterra]

which he *didn't* correct, is not clear. You could try asking him in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/portuguese-language), though =)

Comment: A famous historian who also wrote a grammar. His contribution to this site would be invaluable!

Comment: *Ingraterra* was a variant in use until the 1500s. Maybe by João de Barros' time it became to be regarded as an error, an error that he would still make when he was not on his guard.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have any concrete evidence about the history of that particular name, but sound changes ([metaplasms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplasm)) of this sort are a a very common phenomenon in language evolution.

This change from to /l/ or /r/ (or from/to similar allophones) is known as [rhotacism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism#Portuguese). Look for example at words such as *praça* and *praia*. They have the same origin as the Spanish words *plaza* and *playa*, and suffered rhotacism at some point.

In Brazil, some dialects, specially the "caipira" speak, frequently changes /l/ to /r/ (usually for a [retroflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_approximant) /r/ such as /ɹ/), using "farta" for *falta* and so on.

Comment: Although you offer no evidence to bear out your claims, I think this is the best answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that is an instance of "adjacent metathesis", where two letters, "l" and "r" for that matter, are switched in a word. The process is rather common in many languages.

Comment: Could you, please, back that up with some information about _adjacent metathesis_ or examples in other languages?

Answer (score 1):

Algiers = Argel. Adjacent [metathesis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metathesis)? (Exchanging nearby letters).
Spanish makes the same exchange as Portuguese: Algiers=Argel.
This is not rare in Spanish. In Spanish "Roldan" = French "Roland" (= Italian "Orlando" too!).
This process may be facilitated, in the case of the letters l and r, by the process of in which (liquid) l is replaced by (liquid) r (rhotacism), (although rhotacism alone seems inadequate to explain the reverse, or the exchange occurring twice in nearby letters).
To take another example from Spanish: "celebro" is used by Cervantes (DQ, I, 48) for "cerebro."

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese Stack Exchange, when answering a question it's recommended that you use at least one reliable external reference to strengthen your answer's credibility. If you are just providing an example which is based on a [previous answer](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/714/156), you can instead comment on it, thus avoiding repeating answers.

Answer (score 0):

Porquê Argel/Argélia e não "Alger"/"Algéria"

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/porque-argelargelia-e-nao-algeralgeria/35396

Comment: João, bem-vindo à comunidade. O artigo linkado é relevante e interessante, mas a resposta não devia ser só o link; uma razão é que o artigo linkado pode desaparecer.

Comment: Ou seja, João, uma maneira simples de adequar tua postagem é incluindo nela (copiando) ao menos o trecho mais relevante do texto do link.

Answer (score -1):

Visitando a resposta 2 anos após escrevê-la, percebo que não foi bem aceita. Venho então re-afirmar que:

Nomes de países são frequentemente modificados por outros povos. Porque é que se chama Deutschland de Germany ou Alemanha? Nomes de cidades também. Em Português de Portugal, fala-se Estugarda, mas no Brasil fala-se Stutgart. Fala-se o nome da cidade como ela é. Isso é válido para nomes de pessoas, rios, etc. Cada país chama o outro à sua moda. No que toca o nome de pessoas, nossos amigos de ultramar (sim, "ultramar" está correto, antes que alguém corrija) modificam-nos com frequência.  Enquanto no Brasil dizemos "O Príncipe Charles" e "A Princesa Margareth", em Portugal ouve-se "O Príncipe Carlos" e "A Princesa Margarida".

**De acordo com o autor da referência dada por uma das respostas acima**,

> - O que houve? Nada de mais. **Essas variantes na forma dos topônimos** podem parecer estranhas ao nosso olhar, acostumado ao mundo globalizado do noticiário da TV, mas **são extremamente comuns quando se trata de lugares descobertos ou visitados há centenas de anos. Nossos antepassados interpretaram à sua moda os nomes estranhos que ouviram ― friso: apenas ouviram, porque a escrita, geralmente em alfabetos exóticos, não entrava aqui em cogitação ― e assim fixaram-se certos nomes que destoam dos que são utilizados por outros países. Said Ali, em seu brilhante ensaio Nomes Próprios Geográficos, não fala da Argélia, mas menciona centenas (literalmente) de exemplos de nomes vindos do Alemão, do Francês, do Espanhol e de várias línguas asiáticas que apresentam discrepâncias semelhantes.**
> - No caso do Português (e, em amplitude menor, no Espanhol), devemos também levar em conta que nossos navegadores, por chegarem primeiro a diferentes partes do globo, introduziram no idioma formas que ainda não existiam em nenhuma outra língua. Quando o mundo optou pelas formas francesas, Alger e Algérie (muito mais fiéis, façamos justiça, ao nome árabe), nosso léxico já usava Argel e Argélia há muito tempo. Não haveria razão alguma para mudarmos ― até mesmo porque seria um trabalho insano tentar uniformizar a maneira como as diferentes línguas adaptam esses nomes. Só no norte da África, a Argélia, a Tunísia e o Marrocos já encabeçam uma lista infindável: no Espanhol,Argelia, Túnez e Marruecos; no Inglês, Algeria, Tunisia e Morocco; no Francês, Algérie, Tunisie e Maroc…

Comment: I don't think this explains Argélia ↔ Algeria very well. The swap L ↔ R isn't just "another name". It's somehow the same name, but spelled differently from everywhere else. ***E**stugarda* is like ***e**statística* and _st…_ → _est…_ occurs almost everywhere.

Comment: *Alemanha* comes from [Alemanni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemanni), a confederation within the zone of Germany; it's not a good comparative example for this, it's like when we call the Netherlands by *Holanda*. But Pequim-Beijing **would** be a good comparative example for this question.